# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

currently i am facing above problem in laravel. basically this project is setup on mac OS x and currently i am working on it in Linux. so when i run it is on browser it give me that error. i have also changed the my database details in database file. but now this error comes. so can you please tell me how can i fix it.

Open: /var/www/laravel-projects/wit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php

```
*/
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
{
$username = array_get($config, 'username');
$password = array_get($config, 'password');
return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the database on that linux system as well?

Comment: yes i have the database in my local system.

Comment: Make sure that the database has that same port (3306) available, your program isn't able to detect MySql running so thats why you have that error message. Could be permissions, or different port

Answer (score 6):

I believe in versions of php prior to 5.5 you would use "localhost" (or the host the mysql server is running on if it's not the same host) for the 'host' parameter.  If it is after version 5.5 I think you need to use "localhost:3306" (Not necessarily 3306, this is just the default mysql port, so if you changed that it will be different) .  So if you are on a version of php prior to 5.5 and the code is for verion 5.5 and greater, try changing your mysql connector settings.  Guessing it looks something like:

```
array(
        'host' => "localhost:3306",
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'dbname' => 'database');
)
```

Perhaps try changing this to:

```
array(
            'host' => "localhost",
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'dbname' => 'database');
    )
```

Comment: this is m php version john.  PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 11:59:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

Comment: i have tried in my connection file using localhost:3306. but its not working.

Comment: Is the mysql server running then?  It sounds like it isn't. Run the command "ps auxwww |grep mysql" and make sure there is a mysqld process running.

Comment: Just to help others: I have 5.3 and the solution was to remove the :3306 bit

Comment: I found that `mysql` driver use host `localhost:3306` is ok while `mysqli` driver must use host like `localhost` without the port number.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.6.33-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2018 05:01:31) 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.60, for debian-linux-gnu (armv8l) using readline 6.3

Solution for me was to remove :3306 from my config file.

```
<?php
        define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
        //instead of: define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3306');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'mysql-user');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
        define('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name');
...
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For those who search similar problem solution in laravel 8.

I had this error

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (0)
```

You should check 2 files config/database.php and .env

In my case in .env i changed only db_database username and password

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_app
DB_USERNAME=laravel_db_user
DB_PASSWORD=someP@ssword1234
```

The second line DB_HOST=mysql caused this error, so change it to:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

And it worked fine.

I run mysql on my macos by this command:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

and manage it by phpmyadmin