# SQL Connection error: Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (0)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am not sure why I am getting this connection failed error. I am sure that the sever where the database is located is "localhost:3306". I'm currently using cPanel to access myAdmin.

My php code is

```
<?php

$server = "localhost:3306";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname ="mommyinfo";

$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn-> connect_error){
    die("Connection failed:  " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT title, dateposted FROM post";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["title"] . $row["dateposted"] . "<br>";
    }
}else {
    echo "More posts coming soon!";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

At the top of PHP My Admin it says: 
Server: localhost:3306 »Database: mommyinfo »Table: post

My goal is to get the five most recent posts to display in a div on my website. I've looked it up and I can't seem to find an answer that fixes it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328733/sqlstatehy000-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-localhost3306-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2005\] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328733/sqlstatehy000-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-localhost3306-2)

Answer (score 13):

Remove the port number from the configuration file , just keep the mysql server as localhost and then try.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks are:

- restart your server.
- You review if the service the mysql is starting
- you quit the port
- Or verify with ip address without any port or verify your port
- If in services don't restarting else you stop the mysql server